# prototype method is not a function,why?

Tags: javascript

```
(function(){
  test();
}());

function Class(){
  this.prop = 'hi';
}
Class.prototype.mod = function(num){this.prop = num;}

function test(){
  var c = new Class();
  c.mod('now'); // it'll say it's not a function
  alert(c.prop); // it's work
}
```

I wanna move function and class out to ready function to make code clean up and save memory, but I found the class method does not work.

If I moved prototype to test function, it work, like

```
(function(){
  test();
}());

function Class(){
  this.prop = 'hi';
}


function test(){
  Class.prototype.mod = function(num){this.prop = num;}
  var c = new Class();
  c.mod('now'); // it's ok
  alert(c.prop); 
}
```

why I must to move prototype method to test or ready function?

Comment: The fact that you call it "ready function" seems to suggest you think the self-executing function (`(function(){...}())`) waits for the page to load before executing, which is not true.

Comment: as you say, it's self-executing function and I make this js script bottom of page, like ready.

is it good to make everything in self-executing function I wanna know, thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `.prototype.mod` definition is *after* the function that calls it. Hoisting only helps for the function definition itself (which is why `new Class()` works fine), not for prototype definitions.

This really shouldn't be so hard: prepare your tools first, *then* use them.

Comment: you're right, btw do you have any way to hoist .prototype?